# Change color and add shape to lines on ggplot2 geom_freqpoly

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to add shapes on the lines plotted using geom_freqpoly to give more visibility to them if the plot is printed b/w on paper.

```
data <-  data.frame(time=runif(1000,0,20000),
                   class=c("a","b","c","d"))

ggplot(data, aes(time, colour = class)) + geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 1000) + geom_point(aes(shape=class))
```

but this generates this error:
    'Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y'

How can I solve this error?

Another thing is that I want to use a single colour (eg. blue) to draw the lines
but with `scale_colour_brewer()` I can't change the colour scale, I want to change it because the lightest colour is nearly white and you can barely see it.

How can I add a custom min and max for the colours?

[image]

Comment: I think points are not an option for `geom_freqpoly`. If you really need also points, you should program the frequencies on your own and then plot them through points. For the second question, look at `scale_colour_gradient`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, yeah sure I know, but i want to add shapes on the lines, how can i retrieve the automatically  calculated y variable?

Comment: If you just need different shapes, use `linetype = class`

Comment: @DavidePassaretti using 'scale_colour_gradient' give me this Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: Right. Look at `scale_colour_manual()`.

Comment: In that case I suggest you precalculate the statistics outside of ggplot.

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik , so you can update your answer, to show me how?

Comment: @DavidePassaretti 'linetype = class' work but draw all kind of dotted lines and is hard to follow them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? The error you are getting is being produced by `geom_point` which needs `x` and `y`, so I removed it.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = time, color = class)) + 
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 1000) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme_dark()
```

[image]

If you don't want the dark background, pass manual values from `RColorBrewer`. The following example uses every second color to increase the contrast.

```
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = time, color = class)) + 
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 1000) +
  scale_color_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, name = "Blues")[c(3, 5, 7, 9)])
```

*EDIT*

You can extract summarised data from a ggplot object using `layer_data` function.

```
xy <- layer_data(p1)

ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = count, color = colour)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, name = "Blues")[c(3, 5, 7, 9)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the colours, but the problem is geom_point, i want something like this [eg] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/mLckD.png)

Comment: @mario See the edit. It require some polishing but should get the job done.